Как спарсить сайт с динамической подгрузкой элементов
Есть сайт. На нем есть отзывы, но прогружаются они вместе с прокруткой сайта. Если сайт пролистать до конца - сохраняются только 32 отзыва из условных 500. Уже все перепробовал что мог чтобы спарсить полностью, но результата нет.
Отзывы лежат в элементе "div"{"data-widget":"webListReviews"}. Для парсинга использую Selenium, bs4.
Пожалуйста, подскажите в какую сторону копать, или как можно реализовать.

Сделайте динамический скроллинг с проверкой, закончена страница или нет. Чтобы все отзывы подгружались сделайте скроллинг небольшим по длине с малой задержкой. Далее сохраняйте в множество те отзывы, которые видно.
